Oracle Dpi-1080 connection was closed by ORA-25412
I am receiving the following when the program runs for longer duration; if you restart the node app, the error will not appear and everything will function as it should. This error only happens sporadically. ORA-25412 closed the DPI-1080 connection. Min: 2 max: 18 pool size. Oracle, Knex, and Node.js are the tools I use. Iterations: 16.20.0 Knex: "^2.4.2"; Orthocledb: "^5.1.0". There shouldn't be any connection-related problems, and the application should function properly. Is this configured in any way?
